# How to log incoming request in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a JSON request body like this

```
{  
   "3DSecure":{  
      "paRes":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
   }
}
```

I developed endpoint to log that request.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logging/requests", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String loggingIncomingRequest(@RequestBody AxiPayCargilsRequest request,
                                         HttpServletRequest servletRequest,
                                         ServiceContext serviceContext){

    log.info("!--REQUEST START--!"+request);

    log.info("");
    return null;
}
```

How to log this request can anyone help me from the level of Object creation 
Thanks.

Comment: its depends where you like to log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Add following dependencies in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

and then, initialise logger in all your classes where logging required like,

```
private final static Logger logger  = LogManager.getFormatterLogger(YourClassName.class);
```

Now, you can use logger like,

```
logger.info("Your Logging info");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using filters, you can along all the requests coming into the application.

```
    @Component
    public class SimpleRequestFilter implements Filter {

        private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleCORSFilter.class);

        public SimpleCORSFilter() {
            log.info("SimpleCORSFilter init");
        }

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
                throws IOException, ServletException {

            // HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            log.info("Request URI: " + request.getRequestURI());
            // Similarily, you can log others properties as required.

            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }

        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() {
        }

    }
```

If you want to log, only a said API request, you can follow @Chirag Shah's answer.